# unique html on item index ngRepeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using `ngRepeat` over ***items*** how do I display a specific ***item*** from the set with unique `<div>` hierarchy?

I am using CSS framework  **[Bootstrap 3](http://rnikitin.github.io/)**

Say I have `x` items in my set where the first `y` are always arranged in a particular order, while the remaining `(x-y)` fallback to the normal `<div>` structure. Here are a couple examples of potential outcomes:

**Example 1**

```
<!-- Unique -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-6">Item Text 0</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-3">Item Text 1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-3">Item Text 2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-3">Item Text 3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-3">Item Text 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Remainder -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li>Item Text 5</li>
      <li>Item Text 6</li>
      <li>Item Text 7</li>
      <li>Item Text 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```
<!-- Unique -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-8">Item Text 0</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-12">Item Text 1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-12">Item Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-4">Item Text 3</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-4">Item Text 4</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-4">Item Text 5</div>
</div>
<!-- Remainder -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li>Item Text 6</li>
      <li>Item Text 7</li>
      <li>Item Text 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what's being repeated in your examples. If I understand correctly, maybe you want to nest ng-repeat's, as it seems like you have a hierarchy where the top level item has multiple children.

Comment: @SunilD. `item.text`. The examples are "rendered output" or how I would expect the `<div>` structure to look after each item has been looped through.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could also show the result set you are iterating over. If it's something simple like an array of strings, then you need to add some logic to the elements that are being repeated (use ng-show or ng-hide to include/exclude a tag, or use ng-class to specify a css class, etc). If the result set has a hierarchy to it, then nested ng-repeats might be appropriate.

Comment: @SunilD. Let's assume the condition is on index. Say I have `x` items in my set where the first `y` are always arranged in a particular order, while the remaining `(x-y)` fallback to the normal `<div>` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice array on any like repeating subsections and index number on unique elements.

*Following the examples above this would become:*

**Example 1**

```
<!-- Unique -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-6">{{items[0].text}}</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-3" ng-repeat="item in items | slice:1:5">{{item.text}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Remainder -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-12" ng-repeat="item in items | slice:5">
    <ul>
      <li>{{item.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```
<!-- Unique -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-8">{{items[0].text}}</div>
  <div class="col col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-12" ng-repeat="item in items | slice:1:2>{{item.text}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-4" ng-repeat="item in items | slice:3:5>{{item.text}}</div>
</div>
<!-- Remainder -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | slice:6:8">{{item.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Filters.js**

```
filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return arr.slice(start, end);
  };
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to your own post, I assume that you have an array and you wish to display the first x elements of that array in a particular format and the remaining elements in another format, while using `ng-repeat` to iterate over the elements of the array.

You can make use of the `$index` property. When you use `ng-repeat`, the `$index` property keeps track of the count of the current iteration.

So you could have something like this (where x is the first x elements of the array):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
    <div data-ng-show="$index < x">
        <!-- Structure to be applied to the first x elements of the array -->
    </div>
    <div data-ng-hide="$index < x">
        <!-- Structure to be applied to the remaining elements of the array -->
    </div>
</div>
```